# Python : How to rearrange column (Delimited by space ) in text files?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, text-processing

I have a text file  contains  8 columns separated by space. I want to read the text file and rearrange the column .

```
    111    332 255255 5545 555545 565565 56565 256556
    0000   000 0000   1111 1111   111    25252 66636 
    250233 222 222    258  2525   399      800 3299
```

I want to cut the 5th column and paste it on the 8th column and the datas from column  6,7,8 to moved to column 5,6,7 .Like below

```
    111    332 255255 5545 565565 56565 256556 555545
    0000   000 0000   1111 111    25252 66636  1111
    250233 222 222    258  399    800 3299   2525
```

Here is my code

```
    import csv
    with open( 'tbbt.ctm', 'rb') as fin, open('tbbtout'.txt, 'wb') as fout:
    freader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter = '')
    fwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = '')
    for line in freader:
    line[5], line[6],line[7],line[8] = line[6],line[7],line[8],line[5]
    fwriter.writerow(line)
```

I get a attribute error. Please correct me where I'm wrong ?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix) see -f and -d

Comment: why you use an empty string as delimiter? you should use ' ' (a space)

Comment: Even If I use space it shows this Error ** AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'txt' **

Comment: 'tbbtout'.txt => 'tbbtout.txt'

Comment: Thanks . @PawełKordowski